# Recursive function to serialize a javascript object for an ajax request - is there an easier way?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, serialization

Here is a function and helper that I wrote to serialize a javascript object for sending in an ajax request. Chances are there is a more efficient solution out there somewhere, probably in the jQuery library, but I can't find one. Not one for a javascript object.

```
/*
@author Benjamin Yep
@important - THIS FUNCTION ASSUMES INPUT ENCODED ACCORDING RFC 3986 see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
@param data - Any javascript object or array.
@param pName - The name of the object to be sent in your ajax request.
@return A serialized JSON-encoded object, ready to send in a request.
Usage:
var someObject={
"foo":"bar",
"bars":["foo","bar"],
"object":{
    "foo":1,
    "bar":2",
},
};
var r=makeHttpObject();//new ajax object
r.open("get","example.php",false);
r.send(paramify(someObject,"varname"));
//In example.php
<?php
echo var_dump($_POST['varname']);
?>
//back in the javascript file
console.log(r.responseText);//shows the contents of the object you sent to the server
*/
function paramify(data,pName){
return constructObject(data,pName).substr(1);
}
function constructObject(data,path){
var contents="";
for(var key in data){
    var curpath=path+"["+key+"]";
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(data[key])==='[object Object]'||data[key] instanceof Array){
        if(!(data[key] instanceof Array)||data[key].length!=0){
            if(JSON.stringify(data[key])=="{}"){
                contents+="&"+curpath+"={}";
            }else{
                contents+=constructObject(data[key],curpath);
            }
        }else{
            contents+="&"+curpath+"=[]";
        }
    }
    else{
        contents+="&"+curpath+"="+data[key];
    }
}
return contents;
}
```

Comment: assuming you don't need to support IE<8, you can use JSON.stringify. Also, many xhr libs will accept a plain javascript object (not a JSON string) and handle the encoding for you.

Comment: The problem that I had with sending a JSON encoded string to the server is that each uri-component-encode encoded value that is stored in the JSON is automatically decoded by my server, which isn't an issue with individual variables because I can just re-encode the data serverside, but if it is all in a JSON string; well,  I can't encode the entire string, so the data is essentially lost.

But maybe I should look into using an XHL library; I looked into moo-tools, and that seemed pretty easy to use.

Comment: +1 for Mootools, although almost every library abstracts XHR requests to an easier to use interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as efficiency goes, there isn't really a whole lot of improvement you can make to this kind of function.

You should, however, be able to treat objects and arrays identically in your function.  The `for...in` loop will work just fine with numeric keys.

Also, make sure you encode everything going into the output with `encodeURIComponent()`

Answer (score -1):

Kindly look at this plugin

[jquery json](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)

> This plugin exposes four new methods onto the (root) jQuery object:
>
> toJSON: Serializes a javascript object, number, string, or array into
>   JSON.
>
> evalJSON: Converts from JSON to Javascript, quickly, and is trivial.
>
> secureEvalJSON: Converts from JSON to Javascript, but does so while
>   checking to see if the source is actually JSON, and not with other
>   Javascript statements thrown in.
>
> quoteString: Places quotes around a string, and intelligently escapes
>   any quote, backslash, or control characters.

Comment: He's looking for a way to encode it into a querystring, not json.